# The command "cat" wont read my serial port

Tags: bash, arduino

I have my arduino connected to my mac sending the temperature through /dev/tty.usbserial-A5025XZE serial port. Every second i want my script to save what is coming through the serial port but when i try

```
cat /dev/tty.usbserial-A5025XZE >log.txt
```

It won't write anything to the file and it seems like the command dosn't run, I have to use control - z to cancel it.

Comment: Ctrl-Z doesn't cancel but suspend the process. You may have to kill earlier instances of that command before rerunning.   kill %1  should kill it.

Comment: `cat` is probably buffering its output, so it won't write to the file until it gets a large amount of input, like 4K.

Comment: @Barmar cat isn't buffered, unless you've got a weird build. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix).

Comment: I have this exact same problem, except I want to view the contents of `/dev/tty.SLAB_USBtoUART`

Answer (score 0):

The command is blocked while it waits for data from the serial port. Your Arduino isn't sending anything.

Comment: I can see the info coming through when i using screen tho?

Comment: @lewis You could write a very short C program that reads unbuffered and writes out to definitely prove this is the case, but I'm 100% sure cat is already doing this for you. You may be seeing data on the screen, but it's not making it to the serial port for some reason.

Comment: @lewis Wait, let me make sure I'm understanding what you're saying.. When you say "screen", do you mean if you just say "cat /dev/tty.usbserial-A5025XZE" you see text on your console window, but redirecting to a file doesn't seem to do anything, or is there some other screen that you're talking about?

Comment: @lewis Are you sure you have the correct serial device? Googling around seems to indicate you want to read from /dev/ttyUSB0 or something along those lines.